# Internet explorer playing mp4 videos in media player. Not inside the website

Tags: javascript, html, angular, video, internet-explorer-11

i am trying to create a webpage which other than some other content also includes a video.
because of the reason that i have to append the video url dynamically i am using the `<iframe>` tag isntead of `<video>` tag.
it is working fine in chrome and other browser, But when i am checking it on internet explorer(11) the video is getting played on media player. NOT inside the webpage.

i am not using the html `<video>`. code is something as below.

```
<iframe class="video-responsive-iframe" 
    ng-src="http://trinilearn.vo.llnwd.net/o3/RV/RV-10723/05-profile.mp4"
    frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

i am expecting it to open the video in the webpage itself , but it is always opened in the media player.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning why you don't use `<video>`. The url can be specified dynamically for a `<video>` tag as for an `<iframe>`tag.

Comment: @NineBerry actually one of the reason is that i am using a lot of vimeo player options as well and i am not sure if we can use the same using the video tag.
apart from the reason above when i am using "video" tag , video stops after few seconds only in IE.it is quite strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the video tag instead.

```
<video class="video-responsive-iframe" src="http://trinilearn.vo.llnwd.net/o3/RV/RV-10723/05-profile.mp4" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></video>
```

Comment: currently IE is still ~9% of desktop market. why exclude them (when the question specifically asks how to support them)?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal What do you mean? The video tag is [supported on IE11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Browser_compatibility). Seems like an issue with OPs setup is more likely the problem here.

Comment: @ryan, Seth's original answer included "And don't support IE." as a solution, my comment was in response to that (now removed) snark

Comment: I tried commenting to say that I fixed it, but it wouldn't let me comment.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal i am working for a bank a lot of those wealthy people are not that internet savvy and i think they are still using internet explorer.i can see a lot of traffic coming from IE.
i think all 5% of IE users are my company clients ;)

Comment: i think it has something to do with the video type, i see few videos are working fine in the IE as well..but there are few like the one i have mentioned in my question they directly gets opened in the media player.even if you paste the url in the address bar directly.